# Xcode: C++: including library in project

Tags: c++, xcode

How do I create a new project in Xcode and use this library `libStanfordCPPlib.a` As you see in the img, I have the library file in my project folder. Yet I can not include any of its classes / functions.

[image: xcode]

Comment: It might be easier to guess if you showed some of the errors and warnings but my first thought is that there's probably a .h file (or more) somewhere that contains declarations for the library content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to link the lib file, find the pathname for libStanfordCPPLib.a, then Click the "Assignment2" item on the left hand panel, then find the build-phase tab, then search for Use Lib Path then paste the library folder path there.

Answer (score 0):

have you #included the header? have you selected the library in link binary with libraries? is the header search path valid? if the error is that the compiler cant include the header, it will be a header path problem. if the error is at linking, you havent added the library correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem.

Right click on the .a file (libStanfordCPPLib.a) and select "Show File Inspector"

In the "Inspector" window, press the "Localize" button.

I'm not sure, honestly, what this did different, so if anyone can explain that, go for it.

I'll say that in my case, the .a file seemed to be localized already, and all references seemed to be set right.

How did I get to the state that I was in just before the Localize button worked?
Right click on the Project ("Projectx").
In the menu, click on "Add files to 'Projectx')..."
I selected Destination check box (checked) to copy files into destination folder if needed.
I chose "Create folder references for any added folders"
I chose "add to targets: Projectx"

That's about it.  my header file referenced in the .a kept failing.   Then I clicked the "Localize" button mentioned above and it all worked.